# How to add different colors setCircleColorHole in line graph of MPAndroidChart android?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart, linegraph

There are method to add single circle hole color in the graph for all points.
setCircleHoleColor(Color.RED);

I am adding multiple circle colors using setCircleColors in LineDataSet like this :

```
 ArrayList<Integer> set2CircleColors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 for (int i = 0; i < values2.size(); i++) {
     if (i == values2.size() - 1) {
        set2CircleColors.add(Color.argb(30, 255, 0, 0));
     } else {
        set2CircleColors.add(Color.TRANSPARENT);
     }
  }
  set2.setCircleColors(set2CircleColors);`
```

Now I want to add different circle hole colors inside this circles, how can I do that?

I have tried to customise the library, but no luck for now. I want different circle colors with different hole colors in it using MPAndroidChart library on the line graph points.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this without modifying the actual library code is to just use multiple data sets. You can create one data set with just the line (and no circles) and other data sets with one point each, so you can set whatever colors you want (circle and hole) on each point.

If you have groups of points that would all have the same colors, you can group those together in the same `LineDataSet` too, and just set the line width to 0.

**Kotlin Example:**

I defined a data class to organize the data

```kotlin
data class EntryData(val x: Float, val y: Float, val color: Int, val holeColor: Int)
```

then created the core data to plot (x and y points, and colors per point)

```kotlin
val entries = listOf(
    EntryData(1f, 1.0f, Color.BLACK,  Color.RED),
    EntryData(2f, 1.5f, Color.LTGRAY, Color.BLUE),
    EntryData(3f, 1.2f, Color.GREEN,  Color.MAGENTA)
)
```

then translated the custom data into a `LineData` object, applied formatting, and associated it with the chart

```kotlin
// First create one data set per point and apply formatting
val dataSets = entries.map { e ->
    LineDataSet(listOf(Entry(e.x, e.y)), "").also { ds ->
        ds.setDrawValues(false)
        ds.setCircleColor(e.color)
        ds.circleHoleColor = e.holeColor
        ds.circleRadius = 8f
        ds.circleHoleRadius = 3f
    }
}.toMutableList()

// Then create a data set for the line (if desired) and 
// add it to the list
val lineDs = LineDataSet(entries.map { Entry(it.x, it.y) }, null)
lineDs.setDrawValues(false)
lineDs.color = Color.BLACK
lineDs.lineWidth = 3f
lineDs.setDrawCircles(false)

dataSets.add(0, lineDs)

// associate the data set with the chart
chart.data = LineData(dataSets.toList())

// and some misc formatting for the chart
chart.legend.isEnabled = false
chart.description.isEnabled = false
chart.xAxis.position = XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM
chart.axisRight.isEnabled = false
```

Which gives you a different hole color for each point, like this:

[image: hole colors]

**Java Example:**

The solution in Java is similar. First we create the raw data

```java
ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();
entries.add(new Entry(1f, 1f));
entries.add(new Entry(2f, 1.5f));
entries.add(new Entry(3f, 1.2f));

ArrayList<Integer> circleColors = new ArrayList<>();
circleColors.add(Color.BLACK);
circleColors.add(Color.LTGRAY);
circleColors.add(Color.GREEN);

ArrayList<Integer> holeColors = new ArrayList<>();
holeColors.add(Color.RED);
holeColors.add(Color.BLUE);
holeColors.add(Color.MAGENTA);
```

then transform it into the `LineData` object and associate it with the chart

```java
ArrayList<ILineDataSet> dataSets = new ArrayList<>();

LineDataSet lineDs = new LineDataSet(entries, null);
lineDs.setDrawValues(false);
lineDs.setColor(Color.BLACK);
lineDs.setLineWidth(3f);
lineDs.setDrawCircles(false);
dataSets.add(lineDs);

for(int i = 0; i < entries.size(); ++i) {
    LineDataSet dsi = new LineDataSet(Collections.singletonList(entries.get(i)), null);
    dsi.setDrawValues(false);
    dsi.setCircleColor(circleColors.get(i));
    dsi.setCircleHoleColor(holeColors.get(i));
    dsi.setCircleRadius(8f);
    dsi.setCircleHoleRadius(4f);
    dataSets.add(dsi);
}

chart.setData(new LineData(dataSets));
chart.getLegend().setEnabled(false);
chart.getDescription().setEnabled(false);
chart.getXAxis().setPosition(XAxis.XAxisPosition.BOTTOM);
chart.getAxisRight().setEnabled(false);
```